# this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Tags: git

I am trying to push the files locally to the git repository but by a mistake I committed one big file which is more than 100mb

I am trying to remove it from the commitment but it refused
whenever I try to push i got this mistake

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (283/283), completed with 14 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: f119480af6d77b2c6c04d9e66442bd7cad547d6c27f37616bc5aa42a614ae4bb
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Acar-Yatak.rar is 119.44 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

however when I try to remove it I got this error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'Acar-Yatak.rar' did not match any files
```

Comment: unfortanely not, because somehow the terminal cant see the big file when i try to remove it, but it sees it when i push it

Comment: This is because the file might not be part of your recent commit, but might still be contained in an older commit in your history, which is pushed. Check your Git history for that file

Comment: @HazalKaya you need to follow that questions instructions to remove the file from history. the terminal has nothing to do with that.

Comment: hi, i just checked my last three commits and none of them has it pushed